# Call WslRegisterDistribution function from wslapi.dll in PowerShell

Tags: c#, c++, powershell, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am making a PowerShell script to install any Linux userspace from compressed tarballs (.tar.gz). But it always return some number like this `2147943746`. I am using [`WslRegisterDistribution`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt826870(v=vs.85).aspx) function from `wslapi.dll`. The syntax in C++ is as follows:

```
HRESULT WINAPI WslRegisterDistribution(
  _In_ PCWSTR distroName,
  _In_ PCWSTR tarGzFilename
);
```

My PowerShell script is as follows:

```
$X=Read-Host "Enter Distro Name"
$Y=Read-Host "Enter .tar.gz file path"
Write-Host "Distro name '$X' and file path '$Y'"
pause

$MethodDefinition=@'
[DllImport("wslapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint WslRegisterDistribution(string distributionName, string tarGzFilename);
'@

$WslApi=Add-Type -MemberDefinition $MethodDefinition -Name 'Wslapi' -PassThru
$WslApi::WslRegisterDistribution("$X", "$Y");
```

I can call that method using C++/C# but I can not do that in PowerShell. In C# I import the function and pass two command arguments in its parameter shown as below:

```
[DllImport("wslapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
public static extern uint WslRegisterDistribution(string distributionName, string tarGzFilename);
```

Is that possible to import that in PowerShell? How can I corrent the script to do that? See my alternative GitHub project **https://github.com/Biswa96/WSLInstall**.

#### Further readings:

- [WSL Functions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt826874(v=vs.85).aspx)
- [Use PowerShell to Interact with the Windows API: Part 1](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/06/25/use-powershell-to-interact-with-the-windows-api-part-1/)

Comment: Bit of digging... I believe the 2147943746 HRESULT is mapped from the 1346 Win32 error code, which is a ERROR_BAD_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL.

Comment: Curioser and curioser. It fails in the same way from LINQPad (64-bit build). I wonder what they do to the environment that could possibly cause this.

Comment: Yea, I tried in PS and LINQPad. Neither worked. Will have to look more some other time but I'm not sure if I can find anything.

Comment: Consider looking into the threading model of the process. It could be different between your C# and PowerShell. Quite often issues with `DllImport` can be related with this. If you see a difference, then try to change this for your .NET application to match powershell and check if it still run.